# Using Python 33 code to open code using Python 32

Tags: python, path

I'll explain the title better here,
I want to be able to open up a python file in Python 33, run it and have it open up another python file, but in Python 32.

I found this format and I think it could be a step in the right direction, but I have found nothing which works.

```
fileToBeOpened = '(path here)'
python32Path = r'(path here)'
subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (python32Path, fileToBeOpened))
```

Comment: That looks good to me. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Give us an example path to Python. Also, should `fileToBeOpened` be a `r`aw string as well?

Comment: The error is: " (unicode error)'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 7-8: truncated\xXX escape " and the code:

`xsimPath = 'rungame\xsim.py'`
`python32Path = r'C:\Python32\python.exe'`
`subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (python32Path, xsimPath))`

Comment: You forgot to use a raw string for `xsimPath`.

Comment: You have probably missed making `fileToBeOpened` a raw string as well, as @sweeneyrod mentioned.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you, I have fixed it. It opens up the xsim file in Python 32. However, I'm not sure that I'm much closer to my goal, as I'm met with a new error and I feel very inexperienced. xsim uses Pygame, and it runs perfectly when execute it normally, but when executed using the code discussed here, it fails to load. I get an error with "pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('winp.png'))", it cannot load winp.png, this is in the same folder as xsim, other graphics follow.